# Проблема с bootstrap (SB Admin)

Tags: bootstrap

Поставил себе этот шаблон:
http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin/

Но у меня отображается так:

[image]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас всё отображается верно. Если вы хотите, чтобы фон был до конца страницы, тогда разместите больше информации на странице.

Comment: Ну это я как бы понял, другие варианты есть?